# I get the same value percentile for all rows

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, subquery, percentile

For each borough, what is the 90th percentile number of people injured per intersection?

I have borough column, columns with number of injured that I aggregate it to one column. I need to find the 90th percentile of the injured people. It gives me just one value. I need to get different value for each row (or am I wrong?)

```sql
select distinct borough,count(num_of_injured) as count_all, PERCENTILE_CONT(num_of_injured, 0.9 RESPECT NULLS) OVER() AS percentile90

from`bigquery-public-data.new_york.nypd_mv_collisions` c cross join
  unnest(array[number_of_persons_injured,number_of_pedestrians_injured,number_of_motorist_killed,number_of_cyclist_injured]
    )num_of_injured

where borough!='' 

group by borough,num_of_injured

order by count_all desc

limit 10;
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx4rU.png)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the counts by borough for each num injured, then over 90% are `0`:

```
select  borough, num_of_injured, count(*),
        count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by borough)
from`bigquery-public-data.new_york.nypd_mv_collisions` c cross join
    unnest(array[number_of_persons_injured,number_of_pedestrians_injured,number_of_motorist_killed,number_of_cyclist_injured]
          ) num_of_injured 
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

Hence, the 90th percentile is `0`.